# How to read Tsv file from Azure Data Lake into Power BI

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-lake

I try to read a tsv file from an Azure data Lake, but power BI keep telling that file format is not recognize, is there a way to specify the delimiter type (like this `\t`)?

Answer (score 0):

Power BI supports TSV files from ADLS.

I've just tried it and it worked for me, I did this steps:

1. `Get Data` then select `Azure Data Lake Store`, provide path and credentials.
2. Query appeared on `Fields` tab, right click on it and select `Edit Query`.
3. Here I can see that my file is detected as binary by default. Click on Binary and Power BI will detect type as TSV and import it.
4. Now `Close & Apply` to save changes in query.

If I open this query in Advanced Editor, I can see following transformations (which include delimiter):

```
let
    Source = DataLake.Contents("adl://<my_adls>.azuredatalakestore.net/Test/Test.tsv"),
    Content = Source{[Name=""]}[Content],
    #"Imported CSV" = Csv.Document(Content,[Delimiter="#(tab)", Columns=4, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Imported CSV",{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}, {"Column3", Int64.Type}, {"Column4", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```